# my dataframe contains zip codes for destination and source in 2 separate columns. Required to create new column showing distance b/w these zip codes

Tags: python, data-science, distance, geocode

My zip codes are only from one country US. My specific questions are :

1. what should be the datatype of zip codes? while some are numeric(5 digit); some are also of the format 94621-1481
2. I am running the following code:

---

```
distance=pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')
df3['distance'] = dist.query_postal_code(
    df3['DestZip'].values,
    df3['SourceZip'].values,
)
```

---

but getting this error: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `str` - the error suggests that this is the required input type?